# Why does 3d image cube require background?

Tags: html, css

I have created a 3d photo cube according to instructions from a code school class. There seems to be an error in the instructions. I have fixed the error by adding one line of code, but I am trying to understand why that line of code is necessary.

Here is the code (I put it in a CodePen):

```css
.stage {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red; /* THE LINE IN QUESTION */
  text-align: center;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateY(270deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(270deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photobox">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="cube">
      <img class="side front" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80">
      <img class="side back" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499996860823-5214fcc65f8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=702&q=80">
      <img class="side left" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441786485319-5e0f0c092803?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
      <img class="side right" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510274332963-71d4e866fccf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the .side class CSS, the instructions from the code school didn't include the background-color property. This creates a distortion. When the front image of the cube is facing front, the picture appears as it should. When the back image is facing front, it is covered by the front image, which is now on the back side of the cube. You can tell from the perspective that the front image is in back of the cube, but it is still superimposed on what is now in the front view. The same thing happens with the left and right images. I don't think I'm explaining it very well, so here is the CodePen so you can see what I'm talking about. https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/mdeGqXV You'll see that if the background-color property is commented out, you get the distortion, but if it's not, the cube works as it should.

So why is a background-color necessary for the image cube to display properly when I have an image filling each side? Why do two of the sides appear properly but two others don't when I don't use a background-color?

By the way, the instructions were put together by a teacher who is no longer at the code school, so I can't ask him what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: The line you have added isn't valid CSS. Are you using SCSS?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing tag for `<img>`.

Comment: I did put SCSS on the CodePen for that one line. Sorry I forgot to mention that. And as far as the closing <img> tags I had on there, I have removed them, but the distortion still occurs, so they are not the source of it.

Comment: I have taken off the SCSS and replaced the background property with background-color: red; . It fixes the issue, as did the background property. Without it the issue occurs. So I'm still wondering why that background-color is necessary for the cube to work.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Is there anyone that can answer this please???

Comment: Notice that it's not happening in FF (at least not on my machine). Notice2, it's happening also with `background-color: transparent` and `rgba(what,ever,values,0). I believe that it's  an optimization that goes wrong..

Comment: What is FF? Not familiar with that abbreviation.